# Y-axis should display whole number values from 0 to maxYValue on d3.js without repetition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, yaxis

I want to show values like [0,1,2,..., maxYValue] instead of [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 ... maxYValue].

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height - margin, 0])
      .domain([0, this.maxYValue]); //maxYValue can be any whole. number
```

Original:

```
d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5).tickSize(-width + margin)
```

Modified:

```
d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5).tickSize(-width + margin).tickFormat("f")
```

After using tickFormat("f"), it starts displaying the y-axis values like [0,0,0, 1, 1, 1]. It is rounding off the values. But, I want to set a step value to the y-axis values to get the data like [0,1,2,3,.., maxYValue]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wants all integers up to the `maxYValue`, instead of using `axis.tickFormat` on the auto-generated ticks just use `d3.range` to generate an array based on the scale's domain, and pass that to `axis.tickValues`:

```
d3.axisLeft(y).tickValues(d3.range(y.domain()[0], y.domain()[1] + 1, 1));
```

For instance:

```js
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 12]);

console.log(d3.range(y.domain()[0], y.domain()[1] + 1, 1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If `maxYValue` is not the last value in the scale's domain, just use that variable instead.

Comment: I have edited my question, I already have a range specified for y-axis.